# Calculating number of days per quarter for two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I have a project where if given two dates I need to calculate the number of days between them that is in each quarter. In theory I could use NETWORKDAYS, but I'm having difficulty because many times the duration between the two dates is 1+ years.

It will be easier to show visually. I need the format to look like this:

[image: img1]

Anyone have thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Without the existence of reference columns (containing dates like "10/1/2017" & "12/31/2017") your formula will have to be different in each cell (containing static values). Otherwise, you could add the reference columns or utilize a UDF. UNLESS you want to get into some real fancy formula building, where you pick apart those cells in row 1, but I'm afraid you'd need someone here like @Scott Craner to write something that convoluted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, helper rows that contain the start and end dates of each quarter would make this a lot easier but here is a formula only solution.

**UPDATED**

I realized I made this too complicated.  Here is the streamlined version.

In cell `J2`:

`=MAX(MIN(VALUE(CHOOSE(MID(J1,2,1),"3/31/","6/30/","9/30/","12/31/") & RIGHT(J$1,4)),$H2)-MAX(VALUE(CHOOSE(MID(J1,2,1),"1/1/","4/1/","7/1/","10/1/") & RIGHT(J$1,4)),$G2) + 1,0)`

**Explanation:**

`VALUE(CHOOSE(MID(J1,2,1),"3/31/","6/30/","9/30/","12/31/") & RIGHT(J$1,4)`

This gets the number of the quarter, `MID(J1,2,1)`, and uses that to choose the end date for that quarter.  This is then concatenated with the year, `RIGHT(J$1,4)`. The resulting string is then converted to a number value.

This same approach is used to get the start date, with the appropriate quarter start dates instead.

*Note:  If you have different quarters defined, such as Fiscal Years, then change to match.*

**Resulting simplified formula with descriptive names instead of cell references:**

`=MAX(MIN(QtrEnd, EndDate) - MAX(QtrStart, StartDate) + 1, 0)`

The `MIN(QtrEnd, EndDate) - MAX(QtrStart, StartDate)` subtracts the latest (largest) start date from the earliest (smallest) end date and we add `1` to get the count of days instead of the difference.

The `Max(CountOfDays, 0)` traps any negative values, returning `0` instead.

**Note:** I did not get the same values that you have in your graphic.  I don't think your values are correct.  Unless you have a different start date for Quarter 2 (I'm using 4/1), there is no way you could have 45 days in Q2 2018.

Here are the values I get:

[image: My Values]

Comment: Nice solution and the explanation should allow the OP to use this if they want to use NETWORKDAYS to not count weekends or holidays.

Comment: Yes, I sidestepped the NETWORKDAYS issue as the figures displayed couldn't have been calculated that way.  I probably should have clarified or shown it both ways.

Comment: I wouldn't bother, as your method gave the correct output.  Your explanation is enough for the OP to dissect the formula and get the start and end dates of the quarter.

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I was looking for. Top marks.